# Why, for a linear map $T$ that is not injective, is it the case that there exists a normal vector $x$ such that $Tx=0$?

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

If we have a linear map $T$ which is not injective i know that there exists a vector $x$, with $\| x \| =1$ such that  $$Tx=0$$, but I don't understand why this is case, can you give an intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 3):

$T$ not injective  means the kernel is not $\{0\}$. So take any non-zero vector in $\ker T$ and normalise it.

Answer (score 3):

$T$ is not injective, then $Tx=Ty$ for some $x\neq y$, then $T(x-y)=0$, and $x-y\neq 0$, then $T\frac{(x-y)}{||x-y||}=\frac{T(x-y)}{||x-y||}=0$, and $(x-y)/||x-y||=1$

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case an intuitive explaination is an algebraic one. If two different points $x,y$ have the same image under $T$, then their difference belongs to the kernel of $T$ (as $T$ is linear). This difference is non-zero an can be normalised to give a norm $1$ vector that maps to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If T is not injective there exists $x\in V$, $y\in V$ such that $T(x)=T(y)$ where $x\neq y$. Hence $T(x-y)=0$ where $x-y\neq 0$. In particular $\lVert x-y\rVert\neq0$. Hence 
$$
\frac{x-y}{\lVert x-y\rVert}
$$
is your desired vector.